# What does it mean when a function arguments follow "pass-by-sharing"?

Tags: function, arguments, julia

This is in specific relation to Julia, where they mention this in the docs. I noticed the following happen in my Julia code: I can use values of global variables in the julia functions without even passing them to a function. Can someone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the section of the manual about ["scope"](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/).

Variables act a lot like functions: in

```
function foo(x)
    return bar(x)^2
end
```

you don't have to pass `bar` in as an argument, define it internally, or declare it to be a global function. If you wanted, though, you could define an internal `bar` function that locally overrides the global `bar` function. Variables act similarly: the only time you have to explicitly use `global` is if you're modifying a global variable inside a function.

Comment: It's also worth to note that global variables are not completely global, but scoped to the current module.