# Julia: Passing a DataFrame to a function creates a pointer to the DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, normalization, julia

I have a function in which I normalize first N columns of a DataFrame. I want to return the normalized DataFrame, but leave the original alone. Yet, it seems like the function mutates the passed DataFrame as well!

```
using DataFrames

function normalize(input_df::DataFrame, cols::Array{Int})
    norm_df = input_df
    for i in cols
        norm_df[i] = (input_df[i] - minimum(input_df[i])) / 
            (maximum(input_df[i]) - minimum(input_df[i]))
    end
    norm_df
end

using RDatasets
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")
println("original df:\n", head(iris))

norm_df = normalize(iris, [1:4]);
println("should be the same:\n", head(iris))
```

Output:

```
original df:
6x5 DataFrame
| Row | SepalLength | SepalWidth | PetalLength | PetalWidth | Species  |
|-----|-------------|------------|-------------|------------|----------|
| 1   | 5.1         | 3.5        | 1.4         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 2   | 4.9         | 3.0        | 1.4         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 3   | 4.7         | 3.2        | 1.3         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 4   | 4.6         | 3.1        | 1.5         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 5   | 5.0         | 3.6        | 1.4         | 0.2        | "setosa" |
| 6   | 5.4         | 3.9        | 1.7         | 0.4        | "setosa" |

should be the same:
6x5 DataFrame
| Row | SepalLength | SepalWidth | PetalLength | PetalWidth | Species  |
|-----|-------------|------------|-------------|------------|----------|
| 1   | 0.222222    | 0.625      | 0.0677966   | 0.0416667  | "setosa" |
| 2   | 0.166667    | 0.416667   | 0.0677966   | 0.0416667  | "setosa" |
| 3   | 0.111111    | 0.5        | 0.0508475   | 0.0416667  | "setosa" |
| 4   | 0.0833333   | 0.458333   | 0.0847458   | 0.0416667  | "setosa" |
| 5   | 0.194444    | 0.666667   | 0.0677966   | 0.0416667  | "setosa" |
| 6   | 0.305556    | 0.791667   | 0.118644    | 0.125      | "setosa" |
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Julia uses a behaviour known as "pass-by-sharing". From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Julia function arguments follow a convention sometimes called “pass-by-sharing”, which means that values are not copied when they are passed to functions. Function arguments themselves act as new variable bindings (new locations that can refer to values), but the values they refer to are identical to the passed values. *Modifications to mutable values (such as Arrays) made within a function will be visible to the caller.* This is the same behavior found in Scheme, most Lisps, Python, Ruby and Perl, among other dynamic languages.

In your particular case, what you appear to want to do is create an entirely new and independent DataFrame for your normalize operation. There are two operations for doing this: `copy` and `deepcopy`. If the element type of all your DataFrame columns are immutable (e.g. `Int`, `Float64`, `String`, e.t.c.), then `copy` is sufficient. However, if one of the columns contains a mutable type, then you will need to use `deepcopy`. The function calls look like this:

```
norm_df = copy(input_df)     # Column types are immutable
norm_df = deepcopy(input_df) # At least one column type is mutable
```

Julia typically will require you to do these sorts of things explicitly since creating an independent copy of a large data-frame can be computationally expensive and Julia is a performance-oriented language.

For those who want more detail on the difference between `copy` and `deepcopy`, then, again from the docs, note the following:

> `copy(x)`: Create a shallow copy of x: the outer structure is copied, but not all internal values. For example, copying an array produces a new array with identically-same elements as the original.
>
> `deepcopy(x)`: Create a deep copy of x: everything is copied recursively, resulting in a fully independent object. For example, deep-copying an array produces a new array whose elements are deep-copies of the original elements.

Type `DataFrame` is array-like, and so `deepcopy` is necessary if the elements are mutable. If you're unsure, use `deepcopy` (although it will be slower).

A related SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656545/what-does-it-mean-when-a-function-arguments-follow-pass-by-sharing).

Comment: Thanks! So in which cases is an object copied vs deep-copied? E.g., if I do, `iris2 = iris` and then pass `iris2` to `normalize()`, should `iris` also get modified?

Comment: @AlexanderFlyax Yes, `iris` would get modified. Typically any operation of the form `y=x` will *not* create  a new independent object, regardless of type (although interestingly, for vectors, `y=x[1:end]` *will* (I think) create an independent object). For concrete types like `Int64`, `copy` *will* create a new independent object, but for `Array{Int64}`, `copy` only creates an independent outer structure, but not independent internal elements, hence the need for `deepcopy` when dealing with arrays. `DataFrame` is array-like, and hence `deepcopy` is needed for it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am not trying to be critical of Julia, just trying to understand: why would I need to make a copy of an array if modifying the copy modifies the original array? If I wanted to modify the original array, I would just do that, no? I.e., it seems at best redundant and at worst counter-productive. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderFlyax Good question. I don't know! My best guess is that it revolves around scope, ie, in some circumstances it is useful to have one set of references in one scope (such as a calling function) while also having a independent set of references in a different scope (such as the called function), but both sets of references point to the same object in memory. Please don't take this as gospel. Perhaps you could pose that question as a new SO question (it wouldn't have to be Julia specific) and get a more informed response...